# Multiple conditions in cloud formation resource creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm using a platform condition to control the type of environment that gets spun up on AWS. There are plenty of shared resources, but I need certain EC2 instances with pre-baked AMIs depending on a number conditions.

```
"Parameters": {
"Platform": {
  "Description": "Select platform type - linux or windows",
  "Default": "linux",
  "Type": "String",
  "AllowedValues": [ "linux", "windows", "both" ],
  "ConstraintDescription": "Must enter either linux, windows, or both"
},
```

Then I set the `conditions`.

```
"Conditions" : {
  "LinuxPlatform" : {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "Platform"}, "linux"]},
  "WindowsPlatform" : {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "Platform"}, "windows"]},
  "BothPlatform" : {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "Platform"}, "both"]}
},
```

In a resource I'd like to use either linux or windows to trigger a Windows or Linux Ec2 creation, or use both to deploy every ec2 resource declared.

I've tried the following using `fn:or` in a few ways.

`"Fn::Or": [{"Condition": "LinuxPlatform"}, {"Condition": "BothPlatform" }],`

and...

```
"Condition" : {
   "Fn::Or" : [
      {"Condition" : "LinuxPlatform"},
      {"Condition" : "BothPlatform"}
   ]
}
```

I keep getting the following error when trying to deploying and validating using the aws cli.

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body       file://./cloudformation/deploy.json

A client error (ValidationError) occurred when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template format error: Every Condition member must be a string.
```

Is it possible to evaluate multiple conditions to control resource creation? If not are there any alternatives I could try?

Comment: I am having the same issue with Fn::And - Just want to add this comment so the next person googling "Fn::And" will find this page a little bit easier than I did : )

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try adding

```
"MyCondition": {"Fn::Or": [{"Condition": "LinuxPlatform"}, {"Condition": "BothPlatform" }]}
```

to the bottom of your `Conditions` like that:

```
    "Conditions" : {
        "LinuxPlatform" : {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "Platform"}, "linux"]},
        "WindowsPlatform" : {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "Platform"}, "windows"]},
        "BothPlatform" : {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "Platform"}, "both"]},
        "MyCondition": {"Fn::Or": [{"Condition": "LinuxPlatform"}, {"Condition": "BothPlatform" }]}
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that shortly. The structure is that if I select windows from the drop down during stack creation it will create 50% of the EC2 resources in the template. If I select linux it's the other 50%. I want to be able to select both to have all the instances deployed, mainly for dev and test purposes. Would using the above allow me to do that, or would I need to add windows to the fn::or?

Comment: How is the proposed addition different to the one in the question?

Comment: @Efren It seems the "Condition" in the error message means the “Condition” under a “Resource”, which must be a SINGLE string.

Answer (score 21):

I was looking for the same thing with different scenarios in the YAML format.
Below is the YAML format for the reference.

```
CreateResources: !Or [!Equals [!Ref "Environment", prod], !Equals [!Ref "Environment", dev], !Equals [!Ref "Environment", preprod], !Equals [!Ref "Environment", test]]
```

example

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: 'AWS cloudformation template bucket. '
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Description: Enter the environmet name from allowed values
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - qa
      - dev
      - prod
      - stage
Conditions:
    Prod: !Equals [ !Ref Environment, production]
    dev: !Equals [ !Ref Environment, dev]
    stage: !Equals [ !Ref Environment, stage]
    qa: !Equals [ !Ref Environment, qa]
    CreateResources: !Or [!Equals [!Ref "Environment", prod], !Equals [!Ref "Environment", dev], !Equals [!Ref "Environment", preprod], !Equals [!Ref "Environment", test]]

Resources:
  RenderEngineEFSSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Condition: CreateResources
    Properties:
      GroupDescription:  test SG. 
      GroupName: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref Environment, sgname ] ]
      VpcId: vpc-0e4d5cad992b8d65b
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 2049
          ToPort: 2049
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: Ingress Rule for Lambda to access EFS.
      SecurityGroupEgress: []
```

Comment: The '!' here repressents a negation or is it the normal way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass more than one value for a parameter in CloudFormation Template and apply the `Fn::Equals:` which accepts a list of values then your code will look like:

S3NotificationProvided: !Not [!Equals [!Join ['', !Ref S3NotificationArn], '']]

where `S3NotificationArn` is a parameter of type `CommaDelimitedList`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do some combination like this.

```
Conditions:
  Cond1: !Equals [!Ref TrueOrfalseCheck1, 'true']
  Cond2: !And [ !Condition Cond1, !Equals [!Ref TrueOrfalseCheck2, 'true']]
```