# Multiple conditions on a single Cloudformation resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, multiple-conditions

How do I add multiple conditions for one resource?

The resource needs to be generated upon satisfaction of multiple conditions. mentioned in the `Condition:` attribute of the resource.

[Instrinsic function conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086361/multiple-conditions-in-cloud-formation-resource-creation?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate yours conditions with a comma. From this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html):

> If you have multiple conditions, separate them with commas.

An example of the conditional `And` function can be found in [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-and):

```
"MyAndCondition": {
   "Fn::And": [
      {"Fn::Equals": ["sg-mysggroup", {"Ref": "ASecurityGroup"}]},
      {"Condition": "SomeOtherCondition"}
   ]
}
```

Using the `And` function should allow you to define multiple conditions that must be met for a resource.

Comment: can we specify 2 condition in the resource itself? For example
` "SomeResource":{
 "Condition": ["Condition1", Condition2" ], ....
 } ` ?